# Getting value of all the fields from grdiview control in asp.net using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

i am using jquery for posting selected data of gridview on to the server for insert using jquery but i am getting only one column(i.e. id) but i want all the fields value of selected row. so for that what should i do??

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's easy enough to give your entire row a css class. Just give the row a css class that doesn't actually alter any of your styling. Then, use jquery selectors to get all your inputs:

```
$(".yourClass input")
```